# Iterate over df to compare values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data frame and I need to compare the first entry in column one to the first entry in column two. Then the first entry in column one to the first entry in column three, etc. Basically I want to see if the two values are >0, then do something. Is there a way to do this using a pandas dataframe?

```
0  22 0 44 5 6
1  12 3 56 0 0
2  0  0 1  0 0
3  1  2 0  0 0
```

So I want to see if 22 and 0 are both >0. Then if 22 and 44 are both >0. Then if 22 and 5 are both >0. Then if 22 and 6 are both >0. Then if 12 and 3 are both >0. Then if 12 and 56 are both >0. ...and so on. If a pair has both elements >0 then my code will do something else.

I assume there is an easy way to iterate over rows and columns that I am just missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) per axis=1 - columns, comapre by condition and test if at least one `True` in both by `any` or if necessary test if both are `True` use change `any` to `all`.

First column is filled `NaN`s, so (I hope) is necessary [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) for last column `NaN`s, replace them by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and cast to `boolean`:

```
print (df)
    a  b   c  d  e
0  22  0  44  5  6
1  12  3  56  0  0
2   0  0   1  0  0
3   1  2   0  0  0


def f(x):
    print (x)
    mask = x > 0
    print (mask)
    return mask.any()


df = df.rolling(2, axis=1).apply(f, raw=True).shift(-1, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(bool)
print (df)
       a     b      c      d      e
0   True  True   True   True  False
1   True  True   True  False  False
2  False  True   True  False  False
3   True  True  False  False  False
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was clear in my original question. I just edited it for (hopefully) more clarity. I think that the code you provided is comparing if the elements in different columns are > the elements in the first column. I need to see if both of the values are >0 or not.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this suggestion this might work for you.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[22, 0, 44, 5, 6], [12, 3, 56, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# we ignore the first column since we will use it to compare
columns = df.columns[1:]

# new dataframe for convenience purposes
new_df = df.copy(deep=True)

# iterate through each column and compare the 1st and the iterating column and if both above zero make True or False
for i in columns:
    new_df.iloc[:, i] = (df.iloc[:, 0] > 0) & (new_df.iloc[:, i] > 0)

# check results
new_df
```